# Can we use unix login credentials to connect to CVS Repository on same server

Tags: java, eclipse, unix, version-control, cvs

I have a unix login and I am able to connect to my unix box. But when I try to connect to the CVS repository using the same unix login on the same server I am getting error: *Unknown response received from cvs server*. Itried connecting using eclipse and using the shell command but it did not work. Below is a sample command I'm using:

*cvs -d :ext:username@servername:/CVSROOT_PATH status*

TIA

Comment: `ext` mode uses the ssh or rsh server. Does `ssh username@servername` work?

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for reply but can you elaborate on how to checkout my project from the CVS repository. Could you tell me the exact command.
TIA

Comment: The command in your question ought to work if you have an rsh or ssh server running on your `servername` server. You may have to type `export CVS_RSH=ssh` on your client first, depending how your system is configured.

Comment: (It's not recommended to run an `rsh` server, because it doesn't use encryption or strong authentication. Use `ssh`,)

Comment: I am able to ssh to the server but when I try to create a new repository in eclipse it is showing error: "Unknown response received from cvs server"

Comment: If you type `export CVS_RSH=ssh` and  `cvs -d :ext:username@servername:/CVSROOT_PATH status`, does that work?

Comment: I am getting the following error. I am sure that password is correct as I used the same Id/password to log into my unix machine

`Password:
ksh: cvs:  not found
cvs [status aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)`

Comment: Try `export CVS_SERVER=/full/path/on/the/server/to/the/executable/cvs`

Comment: Tried below commands got the error
cvs -d :ext:username@servername:/CVSROOT_PATH status
export CVS_SERVER=/full/path/on/the/server/to/the/executable/cvs
export CVS_RSH=ssh

`ksh: /XXXX/YYYY/home/ZZZZZ/cvs-1.12.6: cannot execute
cvs [status aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)`

Comment: Login to the server and type `which cvs`. Make sure that command works. If it does, use that pathname for the CVS_SERVER variable.

Comment: Hey Mark 
I changed the CVS_SERVER variable and it worked using command line. But I am unable to connect to the repository using eclipse. Could you please help.
Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? If you're running eclipse on a UNIX system (Ubuntu 14.04, Centos 7, etc), it's probably best to ask over on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I am not running eclipse on unix. It is running on Windows 7

Comment: OK, maybe someone here can help, or you can try asking on http://superuser.com

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help Mark